# Seralizing a scala object into a JSON at compile time

Tags: json, scala, serialization, compilation, sbt

I'm looking for way to serialize a defined object into a JSON and place it in the resources directory at compile-time. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: Probably a macro or sbt task, but more information would be good. What kind of object, how should it be serialized?

Comment: An object that extends a simply trait I defined in a library. So object A extends B, where B is a simple collection of vals. I expose a function in the library the converts a B into a JSON string that is ready to be dumped.

Answer (score 4):

SBT can do stuff like that:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html

A macro would be an alternative, but setting sbt up to compile macros in two stages, is probably more difficult. Also, this only makes sense if calling such a macro should be part of your application code.